# If every sylow subgroup of $ H $ is cyclic, is $ H $ soluble group ?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $ G $ is a finite group and $ H \unlhd G $, such that $ G/H $ is supersoluble. If every sylow subgroup of $ H $ is cyclic, is $ H $ soluble group ?

Comment: Yes, in fact $H$ is metacyclic.  The finite groups with cyclic Sylow subgroups are precisely the finite metacyclic groups.  A proof can be found in Robinson, among other sources.  How $H$ is situated in $G$ appears not to be relevant to the question, unless I've misunderstood something.

Comment: If $|H|$ is odd, then $H$ is solvable by Feit-Thompson. If $2$ divides $|H|$, then $H$ has a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup, and it can be shown that these groups have a unique (and therefore normal) $2'$ Hall-subgroup.

Comment: By which theorem ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919119/a-group-having-a-cyclic-sylow-2-subgroup-has-a-normal-subgroup Here's a proof for the latter theorem.