# Finite group with cyclic Sylow-2 group has a normal subgroup of index 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm working on the following qual problem and I'm not sure how to do parts b and c.

[image]

a) This uses a nifty argument with considering the map $N_G(S) \to \operatorname{Aut}(S)$ via conjugation. And using the fact that $|N_G(S)/C_G(S)|$ is odd, and divides the order of $\operatorname{Aut}(S)$ so it must be 1.

b) Not sure how to proceed after the hint.  I think we're supposed to use strong Cayley's theorem here by saying that the kernel of this homomorphism is the largest normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $S$.

c) No idea how to do this one, but I was thinking if we can show the subgroup has order n(from part b) then we note that $|N||S| = |G|$ and so $NS = G$.

[Source: Jan 2017](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Post_2012_papers/Alg_2012-.pdf)

Comment: (b) think about signs of permutations

Comment: So you mean consider the preimage of $A_n$?

Comment: In the linked post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919119/ , the subgroup $K$ constructed is of index 2 (which is normal automatically).