# Normal subgroups of a group of order $102$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

Let $A(d)$ be the following assertion : If $H$ is a group of order $102$, then $H$ has a normal subgroup of order $d$. Prove as many statements $A(d)$ as possible.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

$A(102)$ and $A(1)$ follow trivially, since $H$ is normal in $H$ and the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$ is normal in $H$.

By the Sylow Theorems, since $102 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 17$, denoting $n_k$ by the number of $k$-Sylow subgroups of $H$, we get $n_2  | 51$ and $n_2 \equiv 1$ (mod $2$), $n_3 | 34$ and $n_3 \equiv 1 $(mod $3$), and $n_{17} | 6$ and $n_{17} \equiv 1$ (mod $17$) $\Rightarrow$ $n_2 = 1,3,17,51$ , $n_3 = 1, 34$ , $n_{17} = 1$.

Thus, by the above, we have a normal Sylow $17$-subgroup of $H$ $\Rightarrow$ $A(17)$ is proven.

Therefore, I've proven $A(1), A(102)$, and $A(17)$ so far.

Are there other assertions $A(d)$ that can be proven here ? I don't see how to prove more assertions $A(d)$ than the three above from Sylow Theory. I'm also not sure of other techniques and machinery to detect what normal subgroups $H$ must necessarily have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a group has twice odd order, then it has a normal subgroup of index 2. See for example [A Group Having a Cyclic Sylow 2-Subgroup Has a Normal Subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919119/a-group-having-a-cyclic-sylow-2-subgroup-has-a-normal-subgroup)

So $H$ has a normal subgroup $N$ of order $3\cdot 17$. Now, show that Sylow subgroups of $N$ are normal. Then they are characteristic in $N$, so normal in $H$. That will give you $A(3)$, $A(17)$ and $A(3\cdot 17)$. It turns out that this is all you can prove. To see this, consider the dihedral group of order $102$. You will see that it has no proper normal subgroup of even order. (Just find the group generated by the conjugacy class of an element of order $2$. This part of the argument works for every group of twice odd order.)

Comment: I see. That index argument is an excellent one - I hadn't seen that before. Thanks, verret!

Comment: One question, though. The order $51$ subgroup of $H$ is normal in $H$, and the order $3$ subgroup of the order $51$ subgroup is normal in the order $51$ subgroup. Why does it directly follow, then, that the order $3$ subgroup is normal in $H$ ? From what I understand, if $H,K$ are subgroups of a group $G$ such that $K$ is normal in $H$ and $H$ is normal in $G$, it doesn't directly follow that $K$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: A normal Sylow subgroups is in fact characteristic. (Or more generally, a normal Hall subgroup.) And a characteristic subgroup of a normal subgroup is characteristic. (All these things are elementary.)