# Cyclic Sylow 2-subgroup$\Rightarrow2$-nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, sylow-theory

In [this,](http://www.ms.uky.edu/%7Ejack/2009-09-02-Sylow.pdf) the author has shown that Burnside showed that if a group has a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup, then it is $2$-nilpotent. I try to read it and posted having problems with these lines in its proof. *An element of order $2^n$ is a product of an odd number of $2^n$-cycles. ... Hence $H=G\cap A_n\neq G$ is a subgroup of index $2$ in $G.$*

Please help me. Any of your help has been helpful to me.

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Comment: This is where this theorem is discussed in great detail:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919119/a-group-having-a-cyclic-sylow-2-subgroup-has-a-normal-subgroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the text says, consider the permutation representation of $G$. Explicitly, this gives an injective group homomorphism $G\rightarrow Sym(G)$. What does an element of order $2^n$, say $g$ get sent to?

Think for a while. $g$ is sent to an odd number of cycles of the same length, where each cycle contains all elements of a coset of the Sylow-2 subgroup it generates. An even-length cycle is odd, and hence $g$ is sent to an odd permutation. That means the image of $G$ isn't contained in $A_m$ ($m=|G|$) so $A_m\cap G$ is a index-$2$ normal subgroup of $G$. I hope this covers your question.

Comment: It is impossible that $|G|=n$ and the Silow 2-subgroup has the order $2^n$.

Comment: @kabenyuk oops misused notation fixed thanks!!